# Number of marriage arrangements if Hall’s condition satisfied

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Show that if a set of $n$ boys satisfies Hall’s marriage condition and each individual boy knows at least $t>n$ girls then the number of possible marriage arrangements between boys and girls is greater than or equal to $t!/(t-n)!$ or if each individual boy knows at least $t\leqslant n$ girls then the number of possible marriage arrangements is greater than or equal to $t!$

The question suggests proof by induction on $n$.

This is an exercise from ***Introduction to Graph Theory*** by Robin J Wilson.

Comment: What is the "then" for your "if" in the first sentence??

Comment: Then the number of possible marriage arrangements between boys and girls is greater than or equal to !/(−)!

Comment: *PLEASE* then write your first sentence to be both grammatical (it currently isn't) *AND* informative (it isn't).

Comment: I think I have fixed it

Comment: No. There’s no answer!